# "log4j.logger.java.sql=DETAIL, roothandle" prints query and resultSet, Is there any way to mask some column fields of query result?

Tags: java, logging, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

*"log4j.logger.java.sql=DETAIL, roothandle"*

When this line is added in log4j properties file, it prints iBatis/myBatis query and results of those queries. 
Result might have password, cardNumber or some other personal information, which I dont want to print in logs.

Is there any way to mask such fields while printing in logs??

Comment: one option is to have the sensitive information in a different mapper xml with some namespace org.test.mapper.sensitive and you can set its log level to ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

Given your package name is com.mypackage
Then remove this line:

"log4j.logger.java.sql=DETAIL, roothandle"

Just make sure this line is in the log4j.properties:

"log4j.logger.com.mypackage=DEBUG, roothandle"

This will result in the log showing:
* The sql statement
* The parameters passed in to the sql

Hope the above helps